# Css media not working, what is the problem?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

This question has been asked a million times, and i have followed the answers but it still doesnt work. what am i doing wrong?
I have in the head

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
```

and here is the intial css

```
    .navbar-nav{
          float:right;
          font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
      }
```

here is the media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .navbar-nav{
    float:right;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}
```

i added the font size so i can visually identify if it works, but id doesnt. what am i doing wrong?

here is my head:

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
<title>Stuff</title>
<meta name="description" content="Simplified Bootstrap template with sticky menu">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Knewave|Merriweather|Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/sticky-menu.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/form.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe get rid of the only screen part? Everything else looks fine. Make sure your HTML and CSS files have both been saved too. And force refresh the page to ensure both files aren't being cached.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/xajosidupe/1/edit?html,css,output - I can't reproduce the problem — https://i.imgur.com/dJlpQCa.gif

Comment: This probably goes without saying but make sure you're sizing the screen SMALLER than 800px wide. `max-width` means it only shows up when its less than that number. If that's not working it's likely that you're not overriding the css correctly. Look in the inspector to see if you stuff is even being applied.

Comment: Question is not that clear. Also, the CSS media is working for me as I tested in JSFiddle. Can you be more specific?

Comment: i followed all the suggestion, i made sure its below 800px in google console view, i removed the only screen and part. its still doesnt work. it just does not work

Comment: yes the css is included, other elements not in a media tag work fine on the page. its just the media part that doesnt work.

Comment: You'll need to provide more code. Likely you have a CSS Specificity issue where it's not overriding the "standard" CSS.

Comment: i added my head, the code i am having issues with is in the main.css file, the default css i am trying to override is in sticky-menu.css

Comment: I found the problem!!! i honeslty feel very very stupid. thank you every one!

Comment: @AynonT May I ask what the problem was (just curious)?

Comment: i hate to admit this but i was looking at my live site, and not my local version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your display's width is larger than 800px, your media query wouldn't match.

Try verifying by setting the `max-width` to a very large number like 10000 and you'll likely see the changes applied.